# Installing Airflow on Windows

Tags: python, windows, cygwin, celery, airflow

I want to install an **airflow worker** on a **windows** machine.

I've pip installed it and then copied the airflow folder from a linux install however this has sent me down a rabbit hole of errors! Cygwin was briefly mentioned in the airflow google groups (see [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/airbnb_airflow/windows/airbnb_airflow/JrE-aJDLm5w/mukzBNJ9CgAJ)) however I am not sure about the robustness of installing everything and keeping it running an emulator?

How to setup an airflow worker in widows: can it be natively installed or should a *nix emulator be used instead?

Answer (score 1):

As of 2018, Airflow should be running on Unix or Linux. if you want to install it on windows machine, probably use a VM as what I did.

Answer (score -2):

1st) install pip

```
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/
```

with `python get-pip.py` or `python3 get-pip.py`

2nd) install airflow

```
https://pythonhosted.org/airflow/installation.html
```

with `pip install airflow`

Comment: Tried that and it doesn't work. Have you tested and got it fully working?